# What are the JavaScript functions supported in post-processing function

Tags: thingsboard

In thingsboard I have a post-processing function for an server attribute update dialog.

[update server attribute widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKMdm.jpg)

[post-processing date value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BK42.jpg)

[post-processing date value fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh29p.jpg)

I need to convert a text value (entered by the user in a widget) into a unix time stamp (milliseconds precision) to store it into an thingsboard attribute.

I also want do use this function to display the value in a formatted ISO date string. Something linke YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.

As I understand, the date.getMonth, getFullYear, ... functions are pretty standard for JavaScript. What do I need to do to use them in thingsboard too?

Is there a better way to convert dates?

Answer (score 1):

You have to call use the `new`-operator to create a date-object.

See [Date - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> The only correct way to instantiate a new Date object is by using the new operator. If you simply call the Date object directly, such as now = Date(), the returned value is a string rather than a Date object.

So instead of

```
var date = Date(value);
```

it should be

```
var date = new Date(value);
```

However, there is a handy and popular javascript date-library called [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Fortunately it is already bundled with Thingsboard and you can use it in widgets and those post-processing functions.